# download multiple files from sftp with Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, curl, ftp

I have to download all files from a ftp folder using Explicit FTP over SSL/TLS. I need that for a jenkins job, running on a windows machine and didnt find any plugins - so I am trying to use a batch script with curl and the following code lists the contents of the folder.

```
set "$FILEPATH=C:\temp"
set "$REMOTEPATH=/files/"
curl -u user:pass --ftp-ssl ftp://hostame.com:port%$REMOTEPATH%  -o %$FILEPATH%
```

I figured out that with curl I have to download files one by one, but how can I achieve to go through all the files in a ftp directory and get them one by one?

Is there a better way to achieve that? I read about mget, but it doesnt seem to work with the explicit ftp over ssl.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I use the data from curl in the for loop? I tried assigning it to varialbe using things like for f in (curl -u user:pass --ftp-ssl ftp://hostame.com:port%$REMOTEPATH%) ... but it complains about the syntax. Do you have an example?

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window to learn the correct syntax…

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt bring it to work with batch directly in the script, so I wrote a python script instead and download it from git and execute it as a step in the pypeline. It has some nice libraries, so it works as a charm.